# in-app purchase in cocosSd-x 3.0

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-x

I am working within a team, and we're at the point of finishing our first cocos2d-x c++ application.

We want to add in-app purchases. for what, we made a search for this. We found 2 solutions:

1- The native solution

2- SOOMLA

What do you think about this, and according to you what is the best solution for in-app purchases with cocos2d-x.

Best regards.

Comment: i also want to do in app for android using cocos2d-x 3.2 ... from couple of weeks i am searching on this but not good help from community ... can you please share your thoughts on this.. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm biased as i'm one of the creators of SOOMLA but I really think that SOOMLA is the better way to go because:

1. We did all the work of integrating to the IAP providers. We fought all the fights for you so you can easily add IAP into your game.
2. The economy model SOOMLA introduces is easy to use and makes things easier for you. It will also allow you to keep your users' balances in a dedicated storage and control your entire game economy.

Again, i'm one of the creators of the SOOMLA framework so my opinion is a bit biased BUT we really believe we make life easier for game developers.

Comment: i also want to do in app for android using cocos2d-x 3.2 ... from couple of weeks i am searching on this but not good help from community ...  I tried SOOMLA but it's still giving me error

Comment: Post your error at http://answers.soom.la